# Elasticity of substitution meaning

Tags: elasticity, elasticity-of-substitution, perfect-complements, ces-function

If I computed an elasticity of substitution of f.e. 0.9 between capital and labour, does this implicate that the factors are rather well substitutable or not? Since for 0 they are perfect complements and for infinity perfect substitutes. So lets say if price for capital sinks there will still be some substitution between capital and labour right?